# Weak convergency vs strong convergency in Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an Hilbert space and let $(x_n)_n \subset \mathcal{H}$ be a sequence s.t.

$$ x_n \rightharpoonup x ~~~,~~~  \| x_n \| \to \|x\| $$

We want to show that $ x_n \to x $.

Now, I know which should be the correct answer, but my original reasoning lead me to the result without using the second condition. Here's my reasoning

Let $\mathcal{B} = \{ e_i \}_{i \in I}$ be a orthonormal Hilbert basis for $\mathcal{H}$. We can write

$$ x = \sum_{i \in I}x^{(i)} e_i$$

where $x^{(i)} \in \mathbb{R}$ are the coordinates of $x$.

By the Riesz-Frechét's representation theorem

$$ x_n \rightharpoonup x \Longleftrightarrow \forall y \in \mathcal{H} ~~ (x_n,y) \to (x,y)$$

In particular, taking $y=e_j$

$$ x_n \rightharpoonup x \Longrightarrow \forall j \in I ~~ (x_n,e_j) \to (x,e_j) \Longrightarrow \\ \Longrightarrow \forall j \in I ~~ x_n^{(j)} \to x^{(j)} $$

thus conclude $x_n \to x$.

May anybody help me pointing out where is the mistake in this reasoning?

Comment: Consider $x_n = e_n$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is just the conclusion you made at the end. You cannot conclude that $x_n \to x$ and to see that, try to show that the difference goes to $0$ and you'll see that you cannot succeed because you have no control over the convergence rate of all the components and that is closely related to the fact that you're in a infinite dimensional space.

Answer (score 0):

As curiosity wrote, you need something more than a mere coordinatewise convergence. Here is a scheme how you can proceed. Denoting $P_N x = \sum_{i=1}^n (x,e_i)e_i$ the projection to the first $N$ coordinates, write $$||x_n - x|| \le ||P_N (x_n - x)|| + ||x_n - P_N x_n|| +  ||x - P_N x||$$ and then notice that $||x_n - P_N x_n|| = \big( ||x_n||^2 - ||P_N x_n||^2\big)^{1/2}$. Take $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$ and then let $N\to\infty$.